# Java BufferedReader Consoleparameter

Tags: java, bufferedreader

My task is to write a little game called "Sokoban". In this subtask, i have to let the program read a file.

When I don't write something after the "java Sokoban" it should read the standard map. 
This works, but it also should read an other file, when I write "java Sokoban example.txt" into the console.

My code for the buffered reader is:

```
public class Sokoban {

public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException {      
    BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("sokoban.txt"));
    String line = null;
    int spielfeldbreite = 0;
    int spielfeldhoehe = 0;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {                                    
        spielfeldbreite = line.length();
        spielfeldhoehe++;                                                       
    }
    br.close();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String eingabe; 
    int playerX = 0;
    int playerY = 0;
    boolean exit = false;
    char[][] room = new char[spielfeldbreite][spielfeldhoehe];                   
    br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("sokoban.txt"))
        ||br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(args[]));
    line = null;
    int zeile = 0;
    int zielfeld = 0;
    int kiste = 0;
    int kisteaufziel = 0;
    int spieler = 0;
    int hashtag = 0;
    int leer = 0;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        for (int spalte = 0; spalte < spielfeldbreite; spalte++) {
            room[spalte][zeile] = line.charAt(spalte);                          
            switch (room[spalte][zeile]) {
                case '@':
                    playerX = spalte;                                           
                    playerY = zeile;                                            
                    spieler++;                                      
                    break; 

                case '.':
                    zielfeld++;                                                 
                    break;

                case '+':
                    playerX = spalte;                                           
                    playerY = zeile;                                            
                    zielfeld++;                                                 
                    spieler++;
                    break; 

                case '*':
                    zielfeld++;                                                 
                    kiste++;                                                    

                    kisteaufziel++;                                             
                    break;

                case '$':
                    kiste++;                                                    
                    break;

                case '#':
                    hashtag++;
                    break;

                case ' ':
                    leer++;
                    break;


                    default:
                    System.out.println("Illegal symbol!");
                    line = null;
                    break;
            }
        }
        zeile++;                                                                
    }
    br.close();
```

I hope everything is understandable. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your problem correctly then all you have to do is to modify the piece of code where `BufferReader` is getting the `fileName`.

In other words, you'll have to check whether you are passing any arguments while running the application and then based on the number of the arguments you choose your `fileName`.

Here is the code snippet:

```
String fileName = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "sokoban.txt";
BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fileName));
```

The first line will check whether you have passed any arguments. If you have passed an argument then it will take the first argument as the `fileName` and if not then it will default to your standard file.

Comment: Java is different from C.  In Java, args[0] is not the program name, it is the first command-line argument.  Your code should be `args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "sokoban.txt"`.

Comment: @VGR I'm sorry for overlooking it. I misread the program name as an argument. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have quite some problems with the code provided here:

1. You close the BufferedReader after the first usage und try to read from it again
2. `br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("sokoban.txt"))
       ||br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(args[]));`does not work as you miss the expression for args.
   Better use an if to determine whiche file to use.
3. You are using `Paths.get("sokoban.txt")` multiple times which is not that bad but changing code to for example read another file is time consuming.
   Maybe use a constant for that defining the file name

And as already posted use

```
String defaultMap = "sokoban.txt";
String fileName = args.length > 1 ? args[1] : defaultMap;
BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fileName));
```